# Laravel Paypal Api and Subscription plan integration. Problems of the self-taught beginner

Tags: php, laravel, paypal

**The emotional part.**

Hello stackoverflow community! Please do not be angry with me for possible stupid questions, the answers to which seem obvious to you. I am learning to program and my only opportunity is to do it myself. I want to understand how I can correctly change my intellection and realize how a real programmer thinks. I will be infinitely grateful if someone sees himself in me and can answer my naive questions.

I am working with web, developing projects with laravel (php) and love it so mutch. My projects now so quite large and functional, but when it comes to third API, I have a full brake. Some individual things when I read, I understand everything, but I cannot put it all together. The problem is that I do not understand someone else's API and how to properly integrate it into my project.

**Technical problem.**

I need to connect simple Paypal Subscription plans to my website. As I understand it, a lot of what I read in the documentation is already deprecated. But I found out about this only after several hours of searching on stackoverflow. I realized that first thing I need, is to create plans manually (https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/billing/plans). But what to do now?

- How can I make it so that an authorized user on my website after
  clicking the button, pays for a subscription, and all the data from
  paypal returnes to my site?
- How can I find out on my website that current user has a subscription
  to papypal subscription plan?

All this about laravel of course. Considering that it is very difficult to find a simple answer, I understand that I have no experience with something obvious. But please, be kind, I have no one else to ask about all that. I started learning Laravel and don't have a professional programmer background.

- Is there a ready-made step-by-step guide on how to integrate
  paypal subscriptions in 2021?
- What are the best laravel packages with solutions for paypal api i
  need to use in 2021?

I am very grateful to you for your time. Low bow for your help and answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To integrate PayPal Subscriptions, [read the guide](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/subscriptions/integrate/). First create a product (essentially a description of what you are selling), then create a plan (essentially the recurring profile information), then create a button that uses that plan (the thing for a payer to click on to give their approval, obviously)

You can crate these things via API calls, or manually in the account interface using links like the one you mentioned:

- For one of your [sandbox Business accounts](https://www.paypal.com/signin?intent=developer&returnUri=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.paypal.com%2Fdeveloper%2Faccounts) --> https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/billing/plans
- For your live account --> https://www.paypal.com/billing/plans

Once you have plan for the account you intend to use, you can create a button using the client_id of [a REST application](https://www.paypal.com/signin?intent=developer&returnUri=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.paypal.com%2Fdeveloper%2Fapplications). This can be done following the instructions in the guide (above), or using a button generator by clicking on the meatballs menu to the right of a Plan name and choosing "Copy Code".

---

To be notified of events when and/or after a user subscribes, such as payments being made, set up a webhook event listener for the [event names](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api-basics/notifications/webhooks/event-names/#subscriptions) you are interested in, notably `PAYMENT.SALE.COMPLETED`. The webhook event messages you receive will contain details about the subscription.

To reconcile new subscriptions and their future webhook events with particular "authorized" users, you may wish to include a `custom_id` as part of the button during each subscription's creation, alongside the Plan ID.  Details on this and other parameters are in [the API reference](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/subscriptions/v1/#subscriptions-create-request-body), but since you will be creating subscriptions using a JS button this goes in the `createSubscription` function of that button.

Comment: Thank you for your participation! And a few more amateur questions :)

Comment: 1. I must have a webhook specified in the IP settings, will it not work without it? 2. What is a webhook in itself, its just an activated script with commands on the paypal side? 3. I do not fully understand how to make a code design on my website, I am not very familiar with curl, but I saw and understood the old code, can I use it for integration or do I need to use additional packages?

Comment: A webhook is a method for PayPal to send event messages to the URL you specify (when creating the webhook). This URL must be publicly-accessible on a server/website so that PayPal can connect to it on demand, similar to a web browser connecting.

Comment: Your question is tagged with PHP so you will likely be using PHP's implementation of curl for any necessary API calls to PayPal endpoints, i.e. `api-m.sandbox.paypal.com` for sandbox or `api-m.paypal.com` for live

Comment: I still keep trying to do everything right. Please tell me, I have to do everything the same as before: Send billing agreement, Execute agreement, ect., after creation a plan, Is there no need for this?

Comment: Billing agreements are not used by current PayPal subscription integrations. Follow the information in the guide.

Comment: Do I understand correctly that the depricated methods differ from the current ones, that I have to transfer all data through smart buttons without installing the paypal sdk package for laravel?

Comment: Don't use any deprecated methods. There is no PHP SDK for the current version of subscriptions, only the buttons and any direct REST API calls you need.

Comment: This is the most important answer that finally put everything in its place in my head! Thank you so much for your support!